# Seleccionar varios checkbox

Tags: reactjs, typescript, checkbox

Estoy teniendo un problema con los checkbox de la librería FormCheck. Antes de explicar el problema, daré el contexto de lo que quiero hacer. Tengo una tabla con varias columnas, una de ellas es solo de checkbox
[image: Imagen de la tabla]

Lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar el checkbox que se encuentra en el encabezado de la tabla, se seleccionen o deseleccionen los demás checkbox. Si selecciono todos los checkbox de forma individual, quiero que se encienda el checkbox del encabezado también. Obviamente también quiero que se puedan seleccionar o deseleccionar individualmente.

El error al que me estoy enfrentando es que al pulsar el checkbox del encabezado, solo se me enciende el de la primera fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que uso, lo que uso es la librería FormCheck y React con TS.

```
 // Estado para controlar los checkboxes individuales
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState<boolean[]>([]);

  // Estado para controlar el checkbox del encabezado
  const [selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (billings && billings.length > 0) {
      setSelectedRows(new Array(billings.length).fill(false));
    } else {
      setSelectedRows([]);
    }
  }, [billings]);

  // Manejador para el checkbox del encabezado
  const handleSelectAll = (e) => {
    const newCheckedState = e.target.checked;
    setSelectAll(newCheckedState);
    setSelectedRows(new Array(billings.length).fill(newCheckedState));
  };

  const handleSelectRow = (position) => {
    const updatedSelectedRows = selectedRows.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );

    setSelectedRows(updatedSelectedRows);

    // Verificar si todos están seleccionados o no
    setSelectAll(updatedSelectedRows.every(Boolean));
  };

return (
//Código que no influye
 <thead>
                <tr className="fw-bold text-muted bg-light">
                  <th className="min-w-60px rounded-start text-center">
                    <FormCheck
                      type="checkbox"
                      checked={selectAll}
                      onChange={handleSelectAll}
                    />
                  </th>

                  <th className="min-w-125px rounded-start text-center">
                    Invoice ID
                  </th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Type</th>
                  <th className="min-w-1250x text-center">Billing Period</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Invoice Date</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Due Date</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Payment Date</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Customer name</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Total Invoice</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px rounded-end text-center">
                    Visible
                  </th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Internal ID</th>
                  <th className="min-w-120px text-center">Customer ID</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              {/* end::Table head */}
              {/* begin::Table body */}
              <tbody>
                {billings.length === 0 ? (
                  <>
                    <tr>
                      <td colSpan={7} className="fw-bold text-center">
                        No data available
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    {[...Array(14)].map((_, index) => (
                      <tr key={index}>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td className="text-center">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </>
                ) : (
                  billings.data &&
                  billings.data.map((billing, index) => (
                    <tr key={billing.id_invoice}>
                      <td className="text-center">
                        <FormCheck
                          type="checkbox"
                          checked={selectedRows[index]}
                          onChange={() => handleSelectRow(index)}
                        />
                      </td>
//Resto del código
```

Comment: ¿Como funcionan los métodos handleSelectAll y handleSelectRow?, ¿En donde crees que puede estar el problema? Hay que agregar mas contexto a la pregunta, esto parece un task